# Angular materials : Basic Usage template

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I would very much like to integrate in my angular app the **Basic Usage template**
from [Angular Materials](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete).[image]

I really like the transition effect when the **<>** is clicked.

I already did a search for that directive on their website but did not find it. The closest thing I managed to find is the [Toolbar](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar), but it's slightly different in the way that the upper corners are not rounded. Also, using a simple ng-show, will not provided that transition.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [angular animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) which is just some simple CSS with transitions. And you are on the right track with `md-toolbar`. The demos use it, you just need to set some CSS to round the top corners.

```
md-card md-toolbar {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
```

Now add some content below the `md-toolbar` that you want to toggle and use `ng-show` on it.

```
<div class="toggle-content" ng-show="open">
    The toggled content!
</div>
```

Then just check the [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) documentation on how to animate it with CSS. What you want to animate here is the height of the `toogle-content` element. When it is hidden, `height: 0` is applied, otherwise `height: 200px`.

```
.toggle-content {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.toggle-content.ng-hide-add, .toggle-content.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: height linear 0.5s;
}

.toggle-content.ng-hide {
  height: 0;
}
```

And of course you need a `md-button` in the toolbar that toggles the content.

```
<md-button ng-click="open = !open">
   Toggle
</md-button>
```

Complete example: http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/XXZPrE

Comment: Hi @kuhnroyal, thanks for the example. I tried to use your example. but when I do not add height:200px in the CSS the transition is not animated. the toggle-content just disappears without any animation. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Ravi Because the height is the property that is being animated, if you remove it the whole thing of course does not work.

Comment: Should it not take the current height of the element as default height if no height is provided? I presume not. But is there a way to manage the animation with custom height ( custom height to 0 and then 0 to custom height on toggle) as compared to fixed height in the example above?

Comment: I don't think CSS animations work without a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement something akin to the `slideToggle()` method in `jquery`. The [Angular Slideables](https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables) directive provides this functionality.

The straight corners are a custom style implemented in addition to the `md-toolbar` directive.

Comment: I was hopping for something more "out-of-the-box". Something like the accordion that ui-bootstrap offers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is the closest thing that I managed to find that suits my needs.

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('ui', ['ui.bootstrap']);


(function() {
  
  angular.module('ui', [ 
    "ui.bootstrap",
      "ngAnimate"
      ]);
  
  var module = angular.module("ui");
  module.controller("controller", function($scope) {

    var model = this;
    model.oneAtATime = true;

    model.Operators = [{
      ReportItemName: "asd"
    }, {
      ReportItemName: "fds"

    }];
  });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ui">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.14.3" data-semver="0.14.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js@0.14.3" data-semver="0.14.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="controller as model">
    <uib-accordion close-others="model.oneAtATime">
      <uib-accordion-group heading="Custom template">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
          I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <h1>Some Content</h1>
      </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Other solutions that provide out-of-the-box functionality are very much welcomed.